# Custom Gson Serializer for anonymous classes

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm trying to provide a generic "Json Serializer" instance of Gson that I can use throughout my codebase, and Gson's "only serialize own properties" feature is getting in my way.

I've got some code which essentially boils down to:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Set<Integer> union = Sets.union(
        ImmutableSet.of(1, 2), 
        ImmutableSet.of(2, 3)
    );

    final Gson gson = new Gson();
    final JsonElement obj = gson.toJsonTree(union);
    System.out.println("is null: " + JsonNull.INSTANCE.equals(obj));
}
```

```
is null: true
```

It looks like the implementation of `Sets.union` builds up an anonymous SetView. I thought I could register a `JsonSerializer` to handle all implentations of SetView, but Gson doesn't use my serializer:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Set<Integer> union = Sets.union(
            ImmutableSet.of(1, 2),
            ImmutableSet.of(2, 3)
    );


    final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(Sets.SetView.class, new ViewSerializer())
            .create();
    System.out.println("is SetView: " + (union instanceof Sets.SetView));
    final JsonElement obj = gson.toJsonTree(union);
    System.out.println("is null: " + JsonNull.INSTANCE.equals(obj));
}

private static class ViewSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Sets.SetView<?>> {
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(final Sets.SetView<?> src, 
                                 final Type typeOfSrc,
                                 final JsonSerializationContext context) {
        System.out.println("I'm being called, hooray!");
        return context.serialize(src.immutableCopy());
    }
}
```

```
is SetView: true
is null: true
```

My custom serializer is never called. Is there a different way that I should be registering this with Gson?

I know that I *could* simply change my code to

```
final JsonElement obj = gson.toJsonTree(union.immutableCopy());
```

but I'd prefer to change my library code (which is used everywhere). It's unrealistic to think that everyone at my company can maintain constant vigilance against methods that *might* return an anonymous implementation of a Collections class.

Comment: You could also call `gson.toJsonTree(union, Set.class);`. There's no adapter you can register that will take precedence over Gson's internal one that excludes anonymous classes.

Comment: Dang. That's not really a great option here, the serializer is supposed to be _pretty generic_. I guess I could walk the object tree and throw if I spot an anonymous class, so my team at least knows to fix their code...

Comment: Added as a feature request to Gson: https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1510 Though I see they've closed similar requests in the past.